# How can I get notified when a change set verification is completed?

Tags: change-set

Is there a native way to get notified (say an email) when my change set verification is completed? I know that Capato and Jenkins have that feature

Comment: Such as an email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can monitor a changeset status via Apex, but you can do it via the MetaDataAPI by polling Salesforce to determine the status of the change set.